# How to use createSelectorHook()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, react-context

I am receiving this error on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-hooks-with-context-jqyjg2?file=/src/App.js): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')

What is the proper way to use [createSelectorHook()](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#custom-context)? Could someone please create a CodeSandbox to illustrate its usage?

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import App from "./App";
import myContext from "./context";
import {
  Provider,
  createStoreHook,
  createDispatchHook,
  createSelectorHook
} from "react-redux";

export const useStore = createStoreHook(myContext);
export const useDispatch = createDispatchHook(myContext);
export const useSelector = createSelectorHook(myContext);

const store = createStore(reducer, 0);
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <Provider store={store} context={myContext}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "./";
import context from "./context";

const Counter = (props) => {
  return (
    <context.Provider value={props}>
      <A />
    </context.Provider>
  );
};

const A = (props) => {
  return <B />;
};

const B = (props) => {
  return <C />;
};

const C = (props) => {
  const v = useSelector((state) => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "DECREMENT" })}>-</button>
          value:<span>{v}</span>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" })}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const stepInput = useRef(1);
  const [step, updateStep] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      step:
      <input
        ref={stepInput}
        type="number"
        onChange={() => updateStep(stepInput.current.value)}
      />
      <Counter step={step} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think react-redux v8.0.0 removed `DefaultRootState` (inferring the state):

```
Now that React-Redux itself is written in TS, we've opted to remove the DefaultRootState type entirely. State generics now default to unknown instead.
```

[source: the release notes](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v8.0.0)

So, `createStoreHook` appears to exist if you'd like to (a) bind to a [custom context](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#custom-context) or, (b) ensure a call to something like `useState().getStore()` returns a properly typed redux store.

Note, I am not positive, if this is a correct or even suggested use case for (b). I also discovered that this works following the documented example for `useAppDispatch`:

```
export const useAppStore = () => useStore<RootState>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Redux 4.0  "createStore" is been deprecated, You can use "configureStore" instead. please refer to the below code :

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
let initialState = {
 counter: 0,
};
function counterReducer(state = initialState, action) {
 if (action.type === 'increment') {
    return { counter: state.counter + 1 };
 } else if (action.type === 'decrement') {
    return { counter: state.counter - 1 };
 } else {
    return state;
 }
}
const store = configureStore({
 reducer: counterReducer,
 preloadedState: initialState,
});
console.log(store.getState, 'redux store');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
 <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
 </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: this works but could